# Prometheus range query rounding off time when used with resolution step

Tags: prometheus, victoriametrics

I have a prometheus metric called http_requests_total which is scraped every 30s. I have created a recording rule to aggregate it at an hourly interval for my UI dashboard. Let's call this new metric increase_http_requests_total_60m.

I want to use this aggregated metric to further aggregate and create increase_http_requests_total_1d. My idea to do this is to do - sum_over_time(increase_http_requests_total_60m[1d:60m]).

However, I realized that the value is coming to be different as compared to increase(http_requests_total[1d]). Upon diving deeper, I realized that increase_http_requests_total_60m[1d:60m] gives me data points which are exactly on the hour i.e. 6pm, 7pm, 8pm, etc. How can I make it so that the data points are actually - now, now - 1hr, now - 2hr, etc.?

Open to other ideas as well to achieve my end goal.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus calculates the `increase()` in a specific way (see below), so `increase(m[1d])` cannot match `sum_over_time(increase(m[1h])[1d:1h])`.

Prometheus has the following issues when calculating the [increase(m[d])](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) at timestamp `t`:

- It ignores the increase of `m` between the last raw sample just before the timestamp `t-d` and the first raw sample on the time range `(t-d ... t]`. Note that the `t-d` timestamp isn't included in the time range.
- It applies extrapolation to the calculated `increase()` result, so it may return unexpected fractional results from time series containing only integer samples. See [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746).

These issues prevent from aggregating `increase()` results in recording rules.

Prometheus developers are going to fix these issues - see [this design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y2Mp041_2v0blnKnZk7keCnJZICeK2YWUQuXH_m4DVc/edit).

P.s. there is an alternative Prometheus-like solution, which handles both issues in an expected way, i.e. `increase(m[X*d]) = sum_over_time(increase(m[d])[X*d:d])` holds true for any `X` and `d`. The system is named VictoriaMetrics. See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) for details.

P.p.s. I'm the author of VictoriaMetrics.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the shortcomings. I'm can tolerate the extrapolation and missing out the first sample.
My problem is correctly summarized by the author of this blog - https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/sysadmin/PrometheusSubqueriesPointTime.


P.S. I have been looking into VictoriaMetrics to replace our current Prometheus instance but still need to evaluate the technical lift for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

use `query_range` api.

`query` api use incorrect timestamp.

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries